# Podman build setting network mode of container for specific RUN step(s)

Tags: docker, containers, podman

I have a Dockerfile that includes some `RUN` commands that starts up a mariadb server for a database import operation.

The problem is `podman build` sets the network mode for the `RUN` commands to `host` by default, which uses the host's network interface - as I understood it from podman's documentation - so, when the mariadb step comes, the server can't start because there's another mariadb instance running on host with the same port - which I can't temporarily stop.

The workaround that worked for me is to add `--network container` flag to the `build` command but, doing this has prevented internet access for other steps that's installing dependencies with `yum`, my guess is that the network namespace created for the build steps don't have external - internet - access.

So, it's sort of a deadlock, to install system dependencies in the image I'm building I have to use host network and, to start services that use network interface I have to use container network which can't access the internet - only with `build` though, while `run`ning containers with user defined bridge network the internet is accessible.

My workaround at the moment is to build twice once with host network and, the other with container network - second time `build` uses the cached images where external dependencies are already installed - so, in such scenario it would be great if we can define which step in `Dockerfile` or `Containerfile` uses host network and which uses bridge network.

I apologize for the long elaboration of the issue and, I've tried to search for this particular case but, couldn't find any clear answer other than building each group of steps manually.

**PS:** I tried to set the `network` flag to my user-defined network which works while running the container but, it's not supported - or I'm not sure how to do it with `build`.

Answer (score 1):

Late reply, but I had the same issue and was able to get around it by adding --network=private.